# Loading web data file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to load a `.csv` file from the web and convert it into a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here's my target page where I want to find a `.csv` file:

> https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html

How can I load a `.csv` file of corresponding items from the webpage and convert into a `panda.DataFrame`?

In addition it would be great if I could get the addresses of the `.csv` files from the web page also.

This would allow me to create a function to convert an item name from the target page, that would return the `.csv` file address like:

```
def data(item): 
    file = 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/'+str(item)+'.csv'
```

However, the addresses of the csv files in the webpage are not all the same pattern.

For example,

```
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/Stat2Data/Cuckoo.csv 
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/cars.csv
```

Quite a lot of files are in different directory, so I need to search 'items' and get the address of the corresponding csv file.

Comment: It seems that it is a bad day today for me. Again waisting my time reading a question which in my eyes is not a question if considering the rules for questions ... The question describes the problem, but is missing the part: what have you done to solve the problem you describe yourself?

Comment: @Claudio, can you show me where it dictates that you must show what you have tried?

Comment: you want to read all datasets from this page?

Comment: See here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions " If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down  and closed." and here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Claudio, so the first link is talking about Homework, and the second does not even contain the word show, and it certainly does not say you *must* do anything.  But I did find [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), and I will try to follow it, so thank  you for the feedback.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/tour : "Include details about what you have tried." - yes I can follow how you feel  ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pandas can read the `csv` directly from the http link:

**Example;**

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/'
    'csv/datasets/OrchardSprays.csv')
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
    Unnamed: 0  decrease  rowpos  colpos treatment
0            1        57       1       1         D
1            2        95       2       1         E
..         ...       ...     ...     ...       ...
62          63         3       7       8         A
63          64        19       8       8         C

[64 rows x 5 columns]
```

**Getting links via scraping:**

To get the links themselves from the front page, we can also use `pandas` to do web scraping for data.  Something like:

```
base_url = 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/'
url = base_url + 'datasets.html'

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'dataframe'},
                  header=0, flavor='html5lib')[0]
```

Will return the data in the table on the page.  Unfortunately for our uses here, this does not work because `pandas` grabs the text on the page, not the links.

**Monkey Patching the scraper to get Links:**

To get the URLs, we can monkey patch the library like:

```
def _text_getter(self, obj):
    text = obj.text
    if text.strip() in ('CSV', 'DOC'):
        try:
            text = base_url + obj.find('a')['href']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            pass
    return text

from pandas.io.html import _BeautifulSoupHtml5LibFrameParser as bsp
bsp._text_getter = _text_getter
```

**Test Code:**

```
base_url = 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/'
url = base_url + 'datasets.html'

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'dataframe'},
                  header=0, flavor='html5lib')[0]

for row in df.head().iterrows():
    print('%-14s: %s' % (row[1].Item, row[1].csv))
```

**Results:**

```
AirPassengers: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv
BJsales      : https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/BJsales.csv
BOD          : https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/BOD.csv
CO2          : https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/CO2.csv
Formaldehyde : https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/Formaldehyde.csv
```